# how to use listagg operator so that the query should fetch comma separated values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT (SELECT STRING_VALUE 
        FROM EMP_NODE_PROPERTIES 
        WHERE NODE_ID=AN.ID ) containedWithin
FROM EMP_NODE AN 
WHERE AN.STORE_ID = ALS.ID 
AND an.TYPE_QNAME_ID=(SELECT ID 
                      FROM EMP_QNAME 
                      where LOCAL_NAME = 'document') 
AND
AND AN.UUID='13456677';
```

from the above query I am getting below error.
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

so how to change the above query so that it should fetch comma separated values

Comment: What is als stands for ? Your alias here: `AN.STORE_ID=ALS.ID AND`

Answer (score 1):

This query won't return error you mentioned because

- there are two ANDs and
- there's no ALS table (or its alias).

I suggest you post something that is correctly written, then we can discuss other errors.

---

Basically, it is either `select string_value ...` or `select id ...` (or even both of them) that return more than a single value.

- The most obvious "solution" is to use `select DISTINCT`
- another one is to include `where rownum = 1`
- or, use aggregate functions, e.g. `select max(string_value) ...`

while the most appropriate option would be to join all tables involved and decide which row (value) is correct and adjust query (i.e. its `WHERE` clause) to make sure that desired value will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(NP.STRING_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NP.STRING_VALUE) 
       as containedWithin
  FROM EMP_NODE N
  JOIN EMP_QNAME Q
    ON N.TYPE_QNAME_ID = Q.ID
  LEFT JOIN EMP_NODE_PROPERTIES NP
    ON NP.NODE_ID = N.ID
 WHERE Q.LOCAL_NAME = 'document'
   AND AN.UUID = '13456677';
```

This is a bit speculative because your original query would not run for the reason explained by Littlefoot.